# Find nlargest of two columns (for tweets in python)

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I have a .csv of tweets and want to find the top tweets, which I am defining for my purposes as the tweets with the most RTs AND Favs. I know I can use nlargest to do this as follows:

toptweets = tweets.nlargest(10, ['retweet_count' , 'favorite_count'])

However, I know I get slightly different results if I change the order of the columns in the brackets because the above code orders by the largest values in retweet_count AND THEN favorite_count (source: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html).

What I'm looking for, though, is a way to order the tweets that doesn't prioritize one column over the other and gives me the tweets that have the highest values in both columns. Any ideas?

Comment: I think what you need is to have some extra criteria that makes one columns values the largest vs the others. Any way I can think of if you want to look at them at the same time is going to look at one then the other. You could also combine the columns into one then sort it largest to smallest.